# FTP портит файлы JS

Tags: javascript, ftp, filezilla

При загрузке и скачивании файлов JS через FileZilla часто вижу, что файлы портятся. Как решить эту проблему?

[image: Испорченный файл]

Comment: Бинарный режим передачи включён? Хотя вообще ftp это атавизм какой-то

Comment: Да, я выставил пункт "Двоичный" в настройках.

Comment: Отвечая на вопрос: решить проблему очень просто, надо пользоваться другими протоколами. Хотя бы sftp

Comment: Я переустановил FileZilla, снова выставил бинарный режим, проблема пропала. Да, думаю, нужно пользоваться другим протоколом.